# Swift: How to continuously send an action from a NSTextField

Tags: swift, nstextfield, continuous, nsslider

I have a `NSTextField` and want to send an action whenever the user changes the value. I checked "Continuous" in the Interface Builder (which works i.e. fine with NSSlider), but the NSTextField only sends his action if I unfocus it. How can I continuously send an action from a NSTextField (using Swift)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the delegate of the text field to the class which is supposed to receive the action and implement

```
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: NSNotification)
```

> This method is invoked when text in a control such as a text field or
>   form changes. The control posts a `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification`
>   notification, and if the control’s delegate implements this method, it
>   is automatically registered to receive the notification. Use the key
>   @"NSFieldEditor" to obtain the field editor from the userInfo
>   dictionary of the notification object.